# How to interactivly resize bars in Amcharts gantt chart?

Tags: javascript, visualization, amcharts, amcharts5

As a base I use this gantt chart from Amcharts:
https://www.amcharts.com/demos/gantt-chart-dates/

[image: amcharts demo gantt chart]

Is there a way to let the user interactivly resize any of the items? I see there is a `resizable` [Option for XY-charts](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/xyseries/#:%7E:text=Indicates%20if%20this%20element%20is%20resizable.) in Amcharts but it doesn't seem to do what I need. Is there any other method of resizing the bars?

Answer (score 0):

It's seems preety complicated to achieve that with amcharts becuase they are preety robust.

there is a an open-source project that will satisfy your needs - [frappe gantt](https://github.com/frappe/gantt), it allows you to drag the bars themself. (I have no connection to the project).